# WordPress images not loading when made new child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a child theme after I upgraded my current WordPress site.

When child theme is activated, none of my images work on the site. My WooCommerce shop won't upload the images but when actually going to product page it uploads image.

Also my admin bar is at the bottom of each page of my website and not sure why. But when I switch back to regular theme, I have no problems.

Comment: ImeiUnlockExpress.com is my website.

Comment: I've updated the Stylesheet.css and function.php pages exactly as they should be and still getting issues.

Comment: When clear cache, they will sometimes upload.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

The images have `opacity: 0` (i.e. they are completely transparent and therefore invisible). I suppose there should be some Javascript that switches this opacity as soon as the images are fully loaded. Probably your child theme doesn't trigger that script (or prevents it to rund in some way)

Comment: Thank you, I am revamping because my refund button is also not working for orders.